# Initialize a class instance with trait fields in constructor

Tags: scala

I have created abstract class and trait

```
abstract class Person(val name: String){
 val tax: Double;
}

trait Employee {
 var salary: Double;
 val tax: Double = salary * 0.3;
}
```

and I want to create an instance of class object

```
val examplePerson = new Person("John") with Employee;
```

I get Erorr

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   object creation impossible, since variable salaryin trait Emplyee of type Double is not defined (Note that variables need to be initialized to be defined) Scala Problem

But i don't know how to set field salary with constructor while initializing. Is it possible?

When I tried setting a default value

```
var salary: Double = 0.0;
```

and then use a setter on examplePerson instance, tax is not changing becouse is immutable (it must be val).

Comment: `val examplePerson = new Person("John") with Employee { override final val salary: Double = ??? }` Or, consider rethinking your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will compile...

```
val examplePerson = new Person("John") with Employee {
  override var salary: Double = 40.1
}
```

...but the `tax` value won't reflect it because the calculation is done before the override.

```
examplePerson.tax  //res0: Double = 0.0
```

One simple fix for that is to make the `tax` value lazy.

```
trait Employee {
  var salary: Double
  lazy val tax: Double = salary * 0.3
}
```

Then the calculation is computed when `tax` is referenced for the first time.

```
examplePerson.tax  //res0: Double = 12.03
```

But be aware that once a `val` is evaluated (lazily or otherwise) it will never change, so if `salary` is ever modified, the `tax` value won't reflect it.

Note: This is Scala, where using `var` is discouraged and semi-colons, `;`, are (mostly) unneeded.

Comment: I was looking for that. Thank you very much